# Why does C# Socket receive correct bytes that have been sent to it AFTER it has been disconnected with reuseSocket=false

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm doing a wrapper for plain C# sockets, and currently testing how it behaves.
This is a test that just sends a single byte via a socket (`connection.SenderSocket`) that has been connected to another socket (`connection.ReceiverSocket`) before, but the receiver socket has long been disconnected prior to that transmission.

Still, the receiver socket receives the correct data as if it has never been disconnected.
This is the case when I specify `reuseSocket: false` at least.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task ReceiveSingleByteFromDisconnectedSocketReturnsFalse()
{
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = CancellationToken;

    //this just creates a listening socket and connects another one to it
    //the Connection struct contains those sockets as SenderSocket and ReceiverSocket
    //and also wrappers for those, that I use for custom Send/Receive methods, called just Sender and Receiver

    //the sockets are both connected at this point, SocketType.Stream and ProtocolType.Tcp
    Connection connection = await Connection.ConnectAsync(cancellationToken);
    
    //here I manually disconnect the receiver socket, before ever sending anything to it
    await connection.ReceiverSocket.DisconnectAsync(false, cancellationToken);
    Assert.IsFalse(connection.ReceiverSocket.Connected);
    
    //wait some time, just to be sure?
    await Task.Delay(3000, cancellationToken);
    
    //now lets send some random value through the sender socket        
    const byte value = 123;
    ArraySegment<byte> sendSegment = CreateSegment(value);
    await connection.Sender.SendAsync(sendSegment, cancellationToken);
    
    //now try to receive the value via the receiver socket, which should obviously fail (read 0 bytes), since the socket has been long disconnected
    ArraySegment<byte> receiveSegment = CreateZeroSegment(1);
    //success indicates whether the Socket.ReceiveAsync() calls' return values summed up to the length of the receiveSegment
    //before e.g. any Socket.ReceiveAsync() returning 0, which would indicate an early disconnect
    bool success = await connection.Receiver.ReceiveAsync(receiveSegment, cancellationToken);

    //but magically, the receive method turns the value in the receive byte segment from zero to the correct one, 123
    byte receivedValue = receiveSegment[0];
    Console.WriteLine($"Received: {receivedValue}");
    
    //success is true of course, because the Socket.ReceiveAsync() method did indeed read the 1 correct byte
    Assert.IsFalse(success);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(value, receivedValue);
}
```

At this point, I assume this is by design? As long as the Socket is not recycled by the system the connection is just silently kept active? Then it's double weird to me that when I specify `reuseSocket: true`, the socket does not receive that 1 byte, but instead waits forever for it to be sent, which is what I would initially expect (wait until reconnect, then return the byte). But it is not consistent with how `reuseSocket: false` behaves.

Edit: As requested by @Stephen Cleary, here's a minimal reproducible example:

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MsbRpcTest.Serialization.Network;

[TestClass]
public class RpcSocketTest
{
    // ReSharper disable once MemberCanBePrivate.Global
    // MSTest needs the public setter
    public TestContext TestContext { private get; set; } = null!;

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task ReceiveSingleByteFromDisconnectedSocketReturnsFalse()
    {
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = TestContext.CancellationTokenSource.Token;

        IPAddress localHost = (await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync("localhost", cancellationToken)).AddressList[0];
        const int serverPort = 50000;

        EndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localHost, serverPort);
        var listenSocket = new Socket(localHost.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listenSocket.Bind(serverEndPoint);
        listenSocket.Listen(1);
        ValueTask<Socket> accept = listenSocket.AcceptAsync(cancellationToken);

        var senderSocket = new Socket(localHost.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        await senderSocket.ConnectAsync(serverEndPoint, cancellationToken);

        //establish connection
        Socket receiverSocket = await accept;

        //now immediately disconnect the receiver socket
        await receiverSocket.DisconnectAsync(false, cancellationToken);
        Assert.IsFalse(receiverSocket.Connected);

        //now lets send some random value through the sender socket        
        const byte value = 123;
        var sendSegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(new[] { value });
        await senderSocket.SendAsync(sendSegment, SocketFlags.None, cancellationToken);

        //now lets try to receive the value from the receiver socket
        var receiveSegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[] { 0 });
        int bytesRead = await receiverSocket.ReceiveAsync(receiveSegment, SocketFlags.None, cancellationToken);

        //log receivedValue
        byte receivedValue = receiveSegment[0];
        Console.WriteLine($"Received: {receivedValue}");

        //expect zero bytes read (actually 1)
        Assert.AreEqual(0, bytesRead);
        //expect the receive buffer to still contain the initialization value 0 (actually the sent byte 123)
        Assert.AreNotEqual(value, receivedValue);
    }
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0>. Actual:<1>. 
   at MsbRpcTest.Serialization.Network.RpcSocketTest.ReceiveSingleByteFromDisconnectedSocketReturnsFalse() in C:\Projects\MsbRpc\MsbRpcTest\Serialization\Network\RpcSocketTest.cs:line 52
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)




Received: 123
```

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example, with all necessary supporting code.

Comment: @StephenCleary added it to the bottom of the post :)